# Wordpress Homepage Redirect to other page

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

SO I have this problem when I go to my main website, for example, www.mysite.com I want to redirect it to www.mysite.com/home I'm using this plugin '[link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). it works but not always, I don't understand why so then I wrote a little script in the header file

`$GetURL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"`

```
if ($GetURL === 'www.mywebsite.com') {
    header('Location: www.mywebsite.com/home');
}
```

But still, it doesn't redirect. what could be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your page as Front Page is Setting -> Reading or

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'function(){
    if(is_front_page()){ 
        wp_redirect(get_permalink('your_page_id'), 301) 
    }
});
```

Comment: hey Maxim thanx for your answer. i Know about Setting-> reading but i dont wanna use it. what im trying to do is that i have a home page set from Settings okay? so whenever somebody enters homepage i want to redirect to another page, i dont want to change homepage i just want to redirect from there. ive used javascript i've used php but noething works i have no idea why

Comment: Are you wanna redirect once or only? If only my action must help you.

Comment: ill explain. there's something wrong with my front page doesnt matter if i change and make new page as front page still there are problems so what i want is whenever someone visits my website for example www.example.com  i want to redirect it to www.example.com/home  this is what im trying to achive

Comment: add_action('template_redirect', 'function(){
    if(is_front_page()){ 
        wp_redirect('your page link') 
    }
});

add this code in your functions.php file. And replace your page link on your real page url. It should redirect users from front page.

Comment: sorry one more question sgould i add this into template's function.php or wp-include->function.php

Comment: functions.php in your theme folder :) all wp-include folder will be replaced by WordPress update.

Comment: didn't work ( it made wordpress admin panel go blank

Answer (score 0):

Maxim's answer helped me redirecting the homepage to a custom post type archive, but it contains two typos. First, there must not be an apostrophe before "function"; second, the wp_redirect command needs to be closed with a semicolon.

This is a version of the code which, put into functions.php, points the front page to the archive of the post type 'project':

```
add_action(
    'template_redirect', 
    function( $post_type ){
        $post_type = 'project';
        if ( is_front_page() ){ 
            wp_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) );
        } 
    }
);
```

Obviously, you can use get_permalink() to redirect to a static page as well.